# Deadlock on out/error buffer

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code:

```
var output = new StringWriter();
var error = new StringWriter();

var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = workingDir,
    FileName = file,
    Arguments = args,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};
p.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => { output.WriteLine(e.Data); };
p.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => { error.WriteLine(e.Data); };

p.Start();

if (!p.WaitForExit((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds))
{
    p.Kill();
    throw new Exception("Timeout expired.");
}

string errorData = error.ToString();
if (errorData.Length > 0)
    throw new Exception(errorData);

return output.ToString();
```

I would expect `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` handlers to be called whenever data becomes available, however that is not happening. For a process that outputs ton of stuff into stdout this code eventually exits on `throw new Exception("Timeout expired.");`. I tried throwing some debug code into handlers, but it is never called. Isn't the whole point of specifying out/err handlers is to have them called asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx):

> The event is enabled during asynchronous read operations on StandardOutput. To start asynchronous read operations, you must redirect the StandardOutput stream of a Process, add your event handler to the OutputDataReceived event, **and call BeginOutputReadLine**. Thereafter, the OutputDataReceived event signals each time the process writes a line to the redirected StandardOutput stream, until the process exits or calls CancelOutputRead.

You are not performing any asynchronous reads, therefore, the event will not be fired.

If you simply add a call to `p.BeginOutputReadline()` after starting the process it will work.  Similarly, to read the error stream, call `BeginErrorReadLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

To start receiving the events from standard output and standard error, you need to call [`BeginOutputReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) and [`BeginErrorReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline.aspx), respectively.